# Designing a Screen with Multiple ViewPager in one Screen

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Here is what I want to achieve.

> [image]

I have already got the first viewpager(image viewer) in place.

How do I include another viewpager with tabs inside the same screen?

Which Layout should I work with?

Any Example Code/Tutorials you would suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try linear layout with orientation vertical and set same weight(android:layout_weight) for both viewpager.Also set the width of linear layout match_parent and viewpagers 0dp

Comment: the layout worked...Used JakeWhartons Indicatir library to display tabs for second viewpager(tabs in middle of screen)

Answer (score 0):

please check this link:

I hope its useful

[reference link 1](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

[reference link 2](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)

you want to swipe images when tab change .right?
I hope its useful to you.

Comment: @dipali.. i have got the first view pager in place(used to swipe images) and its working fine.As mentioned in pic, i want to put in another viewpager in the same screen below first image viewpager. What layout should i use to have two viewpagers in one screen.Is there any example depicting this.Thanks.

Comment: <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/xml_intro_pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

Comment: you can use view pager..if you don't know how to use it?then tell me.i give solution

Comment: i know hw to use it.as i said i hv gt one in place already... anyways thx.. i m implementing it ..let u knw if i fce any issues ..